# Execute CURL command only once in script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, curl, inotify

To explain a little, I am currently monitoring a folder for any changes and when  changes are detected it simply uploads the detected files to my server via rsync. This is working without any issues :

```
#!/bin/bash
time_stamp=$(date +"%B-%d-%Y")
inotifywait -mr /usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos -e create -e moved_to |
  while read path action file; do
  echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
  rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 221" /$path/$file username@myserver.com:~/"$time_stamp"/ 
done
```

I found most of that script here : [Script to monitor folder for new files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files)

Question : I am trying to add the following CURL line to the script above, but as multiple files are being detected at once it is also executing the CURL line multiple times. I am attempting to find a method to prevent the CURL line from being executed more than once when multiple files are detected?

```
curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=XXXXXXX -d "message=Motion Detected";
```

I have tried adding it as a new line directly under the rsync command, as well as using && after the rsync command. Both methods executed the CURL command multiple times.

Example of what I tried :

```
#!/bin/bash
time_stamp=$(date +"%B-%d-%Y")
inotifywait -mr /usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos -e create -e moved_to |
  while read path action file; do
  echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
  rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 221" /$path/$file username@myserver.com:~/"$time_stamp"/ 
  curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=XXXXXXX -d "message=Motion Detected";
done
```

Example of the output :

```
The file 'test30' appeared in directory '/usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos/' via 'CREATE'
sending incremental file list

sent 39 bytes  received 11 bytes  20.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

{
"success": true
}

The file 'test31' appeared in directory '/usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos/' via 'CREATE'
sending incremental file list

sent 39 bytes  received 11 bytes  20.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

{
 "success": true
}
```

The two "success" lines show the CURL command has been executed twice, after each detection and upload.

Please let me know if I forgot to include any information...

Comment: How do you define "multiple files are being detected *at once*"?  I think you need to implement a kind of timeout to determine whether or not to run CURL on each update.

Comment: You'd probably be better off with `close_write` instead of `create`

Comment: Since you're using `rsync`, why does it matter if you run it multiple times in quick succession?

Comment: I probably should have explained further, but this is for a security camera system that creates multiple video files, and these are the files that are being detected/monitored and then uploaded via rsync to my server. @yaegashi

Answer (score 4):

Running `rsync` on every update is also wasteful.  The following script runs `rsync` and `curl` once when there's no activity for 0.1 second since the last event.

```
#!/bin/bash
time_stamp=$(date +"%B-%d-%Y")
inotifywait -mr /usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos -e create -e moved_to |
while true; do
  T=''
  while read $T path action file; do
    echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
    T='-t 0.1'
  done
  rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 221" /usr/lib/unifi-video/data/videos/ username@myserver.com:~/"$time_stamp"/ 
  curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=XXXXXXX -d "message=Motion Detected"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd)? It's pretty much the same as what you have set up manually, except it runs as a proper service.

Comment: Oh yeah I forget about lsyncd which would be much easier and better solution, thanks for this post.  Could you provide a config example to run a custom process (`curl` in OP) on each transfer with some updates aggregated?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to give an example. I just set it up, and let it do its job. You'd probably want to ask a separate question... or even better, ask on an lsync board somewhere. The other option might be to have a different process watch the lsyncd log file, and notify based on that.

Comment: Actually... watching lsyncd's log file is probably the way to go... you'd just end up with the same problem if you tried to work a notification in to the lsyncd config. But if you had something that waited for changes on the lsyncd log file, and then waited until say, a minute since the last change to it, and *then* send out a curl notification, you'd probably end up with what you want.