# Alias to copy a file to a specific file

Tags: linux, alias

I have a scenario where I have a script that monitors a file location and that file location has files copied to it, i.e.  `/home/matt/thefile`.

I want an alias that if I do `place myfile.txt` it will overwrite `/home/matt/thefile` with `myfile.txt`.

Comment: What do you mean by saying “copy it on top” – should `thefile` be overwritten or the content of `myfile.txt` attached to its end?

Comment: It should be overwritten.

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24952/26493 or https://askubuntu.com/q/622971/108339 helps

Comment: The monitor script is already running and working.  It's just that a lot of people are using it and copying files to the target directory that it would be really useful to have an alias for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function would be more appropriate.

In Bourne-like shells:

```
place() { cp -- "$1" /home/matt/thefile; }
```

In shells other than `bash`, `yash` and `posh` you can simplify it to:

```
place() cp -- "$1" /home/matt/thefile
```

In `fish`:

```
function place
  cp -- $argv[1] /home/matt/thefile
end
```

in `rc`/`es`:

```
fn place {
  cp -- $1 /home/matt/the/file
}
```

It's in `(t)csh` that you'd need to use an `alias` as those shells don't have functions (it's also `csh` that introduced aliases in the first place). In `(t)csh` you can use history substitution to allow some kind of argument passing to aliases.

```
alias place 'cp -- \!:1 /home/matt/the/file'
```

When called as `place myfile.txt`, they would copy `myfile.txt` to `~/thefile`

If you wanted something that works regardless of the shell of the user, rather than having them add a shell-specific function/alias to their shell customization file, you'd create a script which you'd add in a directory that is in their command search path. Something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec cp -- "${1?Please give the file to copy as argument}" /home/matt/thefile
```