# keep reading files in an updated dir

Tags: bash, cat, io

I have directory, that gets new .gz files during the day. I'd like to have a scripts that I start in the morning, and which keeps reading the data (and possibly processing it) as the new files are added. What would be the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: Use something based on `inotify` if you are on Linux, or equivalent elsewhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692191

Comment: also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm hoping for a simpler solution, since I just need to read the files. Like if I execute 'awk '{}' the script will just keep reading the input. I want a similar functionality

Comment: See @steve reference: `inotifywait -m /path -e create | while read path action file; do process "$file" ; done` where `process` is your processing part. Put all of it in a file, add execute bits, and start it in the morning.