# File Watcher and send mail

Tags: linux, shell-script

I would like to make a script that detects a new file in different folders like:

- `/home/pedro/XX/file1_082018.zip`
- `/home/pedro/XX/file2_082018.zip`

where `XX` indicates a non-fixed position country name (E.G. Brasil, Argentina, Chile, ...)

Once the new file has been detected, I would like to copy this file somewhere else:

```
cp /home/pedro/BR/file1_082018.zip /home2/pedro/BR/file1_082018.zip
```

And if the copy to the new folder is complete, send a mail to inform.
New file /file1_082018.zip is available.

Comment: This may help, depending on what software you have installed and/or are allowed to use: [script to monitor folders for new files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files)

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/473304/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: I cant install any software =(

Answer (score 0):

According to [cp man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1p.html#EXIT_STATUS), you can check the return code of cp.

```
EXIT STATUS
    The cp utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.
```

The exit code of the last operation is actually saved in the special variable `$?`, for example:

```
cp -v /home/pedro/BR/file1_082018.zip /home2/pedro/BR/file1_082018.zip
echo $? >> exit_status.log
```

Then check the value of `$?`

```
for i in $(cat countries.txt); do      #countries.txt is a file contain directories names

cp -v /home/pedro/${i}/file1_082018.zip /home2/pedro/${i}/file1_082018.zip
echo $? >> exit_status.log

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "there was an error in copying the data" 
 exit
  else
mail -s "Success!" someone@example.com
  fi
```

done

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. The problem is.. i have to check every folder for every country.. like  /home/pedro/BR/   /home/pedro/AR/ /home/pedro/CL/ and copy to the correct folder /home2/pedro/BR/ /home2/pedro/AR/ /home2/pedro/CL/

Comment: Hi @goro thanks again. i will try to be more clear. I have this tree directories /home/pedro/XX .. where XX indicates a country.. So, if we receive any new file inside this folders, i have to copy to another folder, After the copy i have to send a mail with the names of the files coppied and the country.

Comment: I will add this to run on Crontab, to check every hour.

Comment: Eg. If in folder /home/pedro/AR/ have 4 files, and i receive 2 new, i just want to copy this 2 new or I can copy the 4 files and remove after conclude.

Comment: You are a genius... so i use the command rsync -u to update the folder.. and how can i detect witch files was coppied and send a mail ?

Comment: Doesnt work..  cat mylog.log
2018/10/04 16:11:23 [1766] building file list
2018/10/04 16:11:23 [1766] .d.....g... ./
2018/10/04 16:11:23 [1766] .d..t...... AR/
2018/10/04 16:11:23 [1766] sent 266 bytes  received 27 bytes  586.00 bytes/sec
2018/10/04 16:11:23 [1766] total size is 1.73M  speedup is 5907.56

Comment: @Pedro Lopes. Would you please either edit the question or post new question?