# `touch` combined with `find -newer` behaves unexpected in script

Tags: bash, find, touch

### Goal

I was looking for a simple way to check for new files.

As the target system is a minimal embedded Linux platform,
I cannot just install more packages.

### Current Solution

A nice solution seemed to be using `find ... -newer reference.file` and then
repeatedly run that with `touch`ing the *reference.file* in each run, as suggested here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249238/562136

In my case, the code looks like this:

```bash
NEW_FILES=()
WORK_FILE_DIR="/some/folder/path"
REFERENCE_FILE="${WORK_FILE_DIR}/.last_checked_reference"

function find_new_files() {
  mapfile -t NEW_FILES < <(find "$WORK_FILE_DIR" -type f -newerBa "$REFERENCE_FILE" -name "*.txt")

  touch "$REFERENCE_FILE"
}

mkdir -p $WORK_FILE_DIR
touch $REFERENCE_FILE

while true; do
  find_new_files

  for file in "${NEW_FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "New file $file"
    # ... handle file content in multiple steps
  done
  
  echo "--"
  sleep 5
done
```

Note that I actually used `-newerBa` and not just `newer`.

### Expected behaviour

By using `-newerBa` only files *created* after the last access to REFERENCE_FILE should be listed, with the access time being updated on each `touch`.

I expected the output to look like

```
--
--
New file <file1>
--
--
--
New file <file2>
...
```

### Actual behaviour

The output looks like this:

```
--
--
New file <file1>
--
New file <file1>
--
New file <file1>
--
New file <file1>
New file <file2>
--
New file <file1>
New file <file2>
...
```

BUT when I touch the REFERENCE_FILE externally, meaning from my CLI while the script runs, the touch has the expected effect:

```
--
--
New file <file1>
--
New file <file1>
-- <-- at this point, touch REFERENCE_FILE from my CLI
--
New file <file2>
--
New file <file2>
...
```

### What I tried

1. I added `stat $REFERENCE_FILE` to each iteration and can see that
   3 of the 4 times (all but creation date) are updated properly while the script is running.

I checked `stat` when updating the REFERENCE_FILE from my CLI, and I cannot see any difference.

```
16777221 96762726 -rw------- 1 user staff 0 0 
"Feb 25 11:53:24 2023"
"Feb 25 11:53:24 2023"
"Feb 25 11:53:24 2023"
"Feb 25 01:10:39 2023" 
4096 0 0 
<path>/.last_checked_reference
--
16777221 96762726 -rw------- 1 user staff 0 0
"Feb 25 11:53:29 2023"
"Feb 25 11:53:29 2023"
"Feb 25 11:53:29 2023"
"Feb 25 01:10:39 2023"
4096 0 0 
<path>/.last_checked_reference
```

2. Use `touch -a $REFERENCE_FILE` and `touch -m $REFERENCE_FILE`
3. Adjusted file permissions to 666 or 777 to make sure that 600 is not a problem.

### What works

I can completely remove and recreate the REFERENCE_FILE.

```
rm "$REFERENCE_FILE"
touch "$REFERENCE_FILE"
```

### Question

I do not understand why `stat` shows updated times and the script does not work as intended, but then reacts as intended to each `touch` from my CLI.

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Is the file system mounted with the `noatime` option ?

Comment: On the chance that I misunderstood: Wouldn't the `stat` command then show a "-" instead of an actual time for the last access?

Comment: I can't replicate this on Debian. Apart from the B in `-newerBa` not being supported and having to use `-newerca` or `-newerma` instead, it works fine... AFAIU `noatime` should only inhibit atime changes from reads and writes, not change the fact that the atime field still exists, nor manual changes to it through `touch`

Comment: Though note that there's a race there, a file could be created between the moment `find` finishes and the script updates the reference file timestamp. It'd not be listed in that iteration and would be older than the reference on the next, and hence missed completely. You could prevent that by creating a new reference with another name before running `find`, and moving it to place after it, though that might just invert the problem and make some files appear twice.

Comment: Another way would be to just move processed files away from the directory. Then you wouldn't need to care about timestamps at all, any files in the directory would be new and due for handling.

Comment: @ilkkachu that `stat` output format suggests the OP is using some sort of BSD system.

Comment: Are you sure the *handle file content in multiple steps* part you're not showing doesn't recreate the file?

Comment: >> another way would be to just move processed files away  <<
I thought about that.
However, the files are created by another process, which may get duplicate input data. It writes out the data to a file if the file does not exist. So when moving the file, there is a chance would be recreated and again treated as new.

>> Are you sure the handle file content in multiple steps part you're not showing doesn't recreate the file? <<
Yup I also checked that with `stat` and no changes to the timestamps occur.

Comment: `sed -i '' sed-code file` for instance doesn't edit the file in place, it replaces it with a modified copy so the birth time would be new.

Comment: Oh that is a bit embarassing :D I think this might be it, as I am using exactly this. Guess I removed the "important" part of the code thinking its not important

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas feel free to add an answer to be accepted.

Comment: @L.Heinrichs The `atime` is still updated for creates and writes, so all files and directories still have it: the `noatime` just gives file systems the option to suppress updating it on *every* read, either per-file or whole fs. Linux Documentation Project has more detail.