# FTP Upload Hook

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a command when a directory's contents are updated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-to-run-a-command-when-a-directorys-contents-are-updated)

I need to be notified and perform other tasks when a file is uploaded onto my server. Is there any method/system call that will be triggered or anything that I can hook onto?

I'm using vsftpd as my ftp server.

Comment: [This is a similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3070555); `inotify` can also watch directories, so the answers there might help.  (You could also use something like [`pyftpdlib`](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) (or something like that for your language of choice) to integrate the FTP server functionality in your application.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dazukofs` then, but it's unlikely to be supported in latest kernels, you will need to patch it manually.

Many AV uses dazukofs as on-access scan approach.

Comment: According to the website, dazuko has no maintainer and the latest release is more than a year old. It sounds like a heavyweight solution which inotify/similar can solve more easily (and with less kernel patching)