# How to monitor specific files in unix

Tags: backup, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run a command when a directory’s contents are updated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-to-run-a-command-when-a-directorys-contents-are-updated)

Any one know how to monitor files in Unix. I want to take backup of that files when its modified and store it in another server.

Comment: @jasonwryan As far as I know `inotify` is a GNU/Linux tool. If the OP has some other UNIX this will not work.

Comment: @qbi That may be true, but in the absence of any indication as to what OS he is running, I think it reasonable to assume it is Linux. There is an `inotify` for BSD as well...

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` can do that, it will copy only changed files. But it requires to be scheduled. It doesn't monitor a file to copy it upon change, rather it checks for changed files every time when run. Your question is not very specific so it is difficult to give a detailed answer, but I have the impression you want to check the `man rsync` for `--include` and `--exclude`. 
You can schedule a command like this using `cron`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run something like [Tripwire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Tripwire) which would alert you or do an action when it detected a change.

A simpler method would be to use find

```
find (path to files) -mmin 60 -type f
```

you can then do something like

```
find (path to files) -mmin 60 -type f -exec gzip -9 {} \; -exec mv {}.gz_`date +%F`.gz (path to new location) \;
```