# How do I sync dropbox folders to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arch-linux, synchronization, raspberry-pi, dropbox

I have been using a script that uses curl to sync dropbox folders to a Raspberry Pi. Cron calls the script every hour to retrieve most of the folders.

Can anyone recommend a better solution, maybe one that checks if the folder has changed since the last sync.

I don't want to install the official dropbox app because it requires many dependencies and I'm running a very lightweight Arch distribution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a command when a directory's contents are updated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-to-run-a-command-when-a-directorys-contents-are-updated)

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to Dropbox might be [Synchthing](https://syncthing.net/), which syncs one or several folders between a cluster of machines (even some mobile phones).

More information about running Synchthing on Arch Linux can be found on the [Arch Linux wiki page on exactly this topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syncthing).

I have used Syncthing to sync the NetBSD `pkgsrc` repository between several geographically distant machines (this a few gigabytes and more than 200000 files).