# How can I get notified by everything that happens in a specific channel in irssi?

Tags: irc, irssi

(Be it hilight/highlight or a beep).
I have a small channel that I need to know all the info of. I couldn't get trigger.pl to work. I could do "/hilight -mask every_single_nick" but that's not efficient enough.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for superuser. See the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for information on the types of questions that are on topic here.

Comment: what about `/hilight -regex . -channels channel`?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman How so? As it says in the [faq#ask]: “Applications packaged in *nix distributions *(note: being [cross-platform does not disqualify](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/97/29))*”. This question is perfectly on-topic here as long as irssi is running on a unix system. As you can see, there's already an answer that uses a unix feature that isn't part of the application — that's part of why we allow questions about cross-platform applications.

Comment: @Gilles My mistake. I will try to make better judgements in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable `autolog` in your config, you can have `irssi` log all activity in your channel. You can then use `inotify` to watch your log directory or file and feed that activity to your notification system.

See [How to run a command when a directory's contents are updated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-to-run-a-command-when-a-directorys-contents-are-updated).

Comment: IMO it is much simpler to just write an irssi plugin with perl then use inotify for something like that

Comment: For someone that can write irssi plugins in perl, I am sure it would be...