# Running a bash script each time a file is uploaded?

Tags: bash, ftp

I have an FTP server (Debian) setup where users send JPG images.

I need a process running on the background that every time a picture is sent via FTP a bash script is executed for generating thumbnail files for each image uploaded.

I already have the script that generates the thumbnail, the problem is it needs to be executed manually, but what I want is the script to be executed each time an image file is uploaded.

How can this work?

Comment: several possibilities, `auditd` to watch a folder, your ftp daemon allow to execute a script on each upload, or a cron job every minute to generate it every minute or every 5 minutes with a temp image when thumbnail not yet generated

Comment: Not really a duplicate. The other question is more generic, this one is more specific, and can be solved in ways the other can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `inotifywait`

eg watch a directory

```
inotifywait .
```

Then create a file in that direectory.

Here's a [previous answer from Unix/Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24030/31760)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your FTP server.

For example, for `pure-ftpd`, you do it this way:

1. Set the option `CallUploadScript` to `yes` (just create a file called `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/CallUploadScript` and write `yes` in it)
2. In `/etc/default/pure-ftpd-common`, add the path to the script you want to run on each upload after `UPLOADSCRIPT=`.
3. Restart the service (`# service pure-ftpd restart`).

Other FTP servers have their own ways. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Also possible to use `ftpwatch` ftpwatch - "Notifies you of changes on remote ftp servers"

```
 # the crontab line
 47 5    * * 7 /usr/bin/ftpwatch
```