# Is it possible triggering a script with a change of amount of files in a directory?

Tags: centos, scripting

Is it possible to create some kind of directory watcher and trigger a script when the folder is not empty?

I have a CentOS machine with jenkins CI on it. i would like to create a job that will move all build artifacts to my web server folder each successful build.
is it possible?

I want to avoid timed triggered cronjob.

Comment: `watch` is what you need.

Comment: did you try [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=why&lang=en)? See [similar question in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/in-linux-how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes).

Comment: thanks, watch is not what i am looking for... i think inotify will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `inotifywait` it can monitor a directory, check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119151/running-a-bash-script-each-time-a-file-is-uploaded/119159#119159).